# QT Images- Loading and scrolling

Tags: qt

I am getting back into learning QT and I am attempting to create a simple app that will scroll through images frame by frame (no. of images is known), and the scrolling will respond with a change in velocity depending on the intensity of the users scroll.  A fast intense 'scroll' will result a jerky animation between frames and a slower scroll will just scroll through frame by frame, with less acceleration between the viewed images. (Kind of like a video playback using the scrollbar-- but without the bar there)

I am just starting so I am looking for an efficient way to handle the images and to have good user interaction. I am not really sure where to start-- my extent of programming with QT was creating event listeners and widgets...so this will be a challenge!

If anyone has any structure, or class or implementation suggestions I am all ears!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

model/view.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html

and use the examples in qt. Just search for: "model view" in the examples section.

You create a list with all the items you want, and you show it in a listview. I am not exactly sure on the scrolling thing though but in QML, the model/view is pretty neat.